# If image exists, display that, otherwise show new selected upload

Tags: php

I have a post.php where you fill in the post information, post_display.php where it shows the post obviously, and post_edit.php where you can edit the post.
The post.php and post_edit.php are very similar as the edit just gets all the information from the database and updates it if any changes are made.

In the post_edit.php file - in the form I have the upload button called 'cover' and hidden input called 'cover'.

```
<?php
    if (file_exists($cover) === true){
      echo '<img src="'. $cover . '" alt="'. $title .'" id="cover">';
    }else{
      echo '<img src="images/blank_cover.jpg" alt="'. $title .'" id="cover">';
        }
 ?> 

    <div class="ad_upload_btn">
    <input type="file" name="cover" onchange="readURL(this);"><div class="ad_upload_btn_text">Change Cover Image</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cover" value="<?php echo $cover; ?>">
    </div>
```

then when the form is submitted, i have this check

```
if (!empty($_FILES['cover'])){
    if ($_FILES['cover']['size'] == 0) {        
            $file_path = $_POST['cover'];
        }

    }       
    else{
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        $file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['cover']['size'];
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true){            
            $file_path = 'images/cover/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
            move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Incorrect file type. Only allowed: ' . implode(', ', $allowed) . '';                                       
        }
    }
}
```

in my database table i have a `cover` row that takes the path of the image and when i echo it, i simply retrieve image/cover/imagename.jpg into my  code.

Right now, if i upload an image it will work fine. But if I don't upload any image, it will remove the old one that was there and replace it with nothing. How can i tell it to display the old stored image rather than removing everything if no new file is selected to be uploaded?

UPDATE:
insert code:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
                $update_ad = array(
                'title'         => $_POST['title'], 
                'price'         => $_POST['price'], 
                'description'   => $_POST['description'],
                'category_id'   => $_POST['category_id'],
                'cover'         => mysql_real_escape_string($file_path)
                );
                edit_ad($id, $update_ad);                       
                header('Location: post_display.php?id=' . $id);
                exit();  
            } 

function create_ad($create_data){
array_walk($create_data, 'array_sanitize');

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($create_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $create_data) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
```

Comment: [`Didn't you ask this already?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21693250/)

Comment: yes and no one is answering and i still can't figure it out

Comment: *"But if I don't upload any image, it will remove the old one that was there and replace it with nothing."*- Why not just use a conditional statement to check if `$_FILES` is set/empty, instead of going through the trouble of checking the DB?

Comment: Instead of doing `if(!empty($_FILES['cover']))` you should be reversing that to `if(empty($_FILES['cover'])){die();}` depending on which `$_FILES` you want to check. (End of story) ;-)

Comment: Instead of `if(!empty($_FILES['cover'])){ if ($_FILES['cover']['size'] == 0)` 
why not try `if(!empty($_FILES['cover']) && ($_FILES['cover']['size'] == 0)) else{die();}` - or replace `&&` with `||` then use `else` after.

Comment: i tried doing that, the else{die();} just threw me to an empty page. i tried doing else{$file_path = $cover; } which is the file path and it didn't work

Comment: It brings you to an empty page, because you aren't telling it to go to another page. `die();` has options you can use to show a message if you want. I.e.: `die("Sorry no Love");` or if you want to echo, you need to add `exit();` after. I.e.: `else{echo "Sorry"; exit();` type of thing. You can also use `header("Location: sorry.php");` to redirect.

Comment: okay so can i do else{ //inset existing image if nothing selected } ?

Comment: Yes you can. That would work. (Should work) ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. I can put my comments in an answer which you can accept if you wish.

Comment: That worked!! But now the rest of the ad doesn't change haha! oh well i will play around with it! yeah do that ill click accept!

Comment: Once you've gotten the feel of the conditional statements, and the options available, you will make it work, am sure :)

Comment: Another note: you should check the **mime type** of the file instead of breaking apart the filename. I could easily rename a malicious exe file to .jpg and it would get uploaded to your server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comments to answer:** (to close the question)

Instead of:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['cover'])){ if ($_FILES['cover']['size'] == 0)
```

why not try

```
if(!empty($_FILES['cover']) && ($_FILES['cover']['size'] == 0)) else{die();}
```

or replace `&&` with `||` then use `else` after.

`die();` has options you can use to show a message if you want. I.e.: `die("Sorry no Love");` or if you want to echo, you need to add `exit();` after.

I.e.: `else{echo "Sorry"; exit();}` type of thing.

You can also use `header("Location: sorry.php");` to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, if i upload an image it will work fine. But if I don't upload any image, it will remove the old one that was there and replace it with nothing.

Based on this statement this is something the database should handle. It sounds like your table accepts NULL in that field. If you run a check before insertion to see if the file path is null you can tell it to use the old file path instead.

EXAMPLE:

```
    'cover'         => " CASE WHEN (mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) != '' AND mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) IS NOT NULL) 
                         THEN mysql_real_escape_string($file_path)
                          ELSE
                              (SELECT cover
                                 FROM (SELECT cover
                                         FROM posts
                                        WHERE category_id = $_POST['category_id']) AS temp)
                          END"
```

This is my more specific wild stab at it. I am assuming that category_id is unique, if not use whatever column that is.
Even if this doesnt work the concept is here.

This is my more specific wild stab at it. I am assuming that category_id is unique, if not use whatever column that is.
Even if this doesnt work the concept is here.

Comment: the thing that i cant figure out how to do is how tell it to use the old file path?

Comment: Just finished my editing but I cant be more specific without the insert code.

Comment: i updated my first post with the insert code. is this the only way to do this? i was hoping to use if statements like i started